# Can GAMME be used directly on the exchange server

Tags: migration, g-suite

I am migrating from a 2003 exchange server and wonder if I can put the GAMME tool directly onto the exchange server and migrate from there.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer on google support

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179197